# can you define working directory for bower?

Tags: bower, package-managers, automated-deploy

can you define the working directory for bower? or tell it where I want the install to run at? ie: like the composer working directory flag?

`--working-dir (-d)    If specified, use the given directory as working directory.`

Comment: Is the `directory` config not what you are looking for, or are you wanting a global configuration?

Comment: The directory config is not what I want - I'm looking for something to assist in automated deployment script.  but I need to define where bower should be run from.  the --config.cwd flag seems to work, and will create a bower_components directory w/ the required files - but ignores the 'directory' config in my .bowerrc file in that directory?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Bower now supports config.cwd http://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#cwd

```
bower install jquery --config.cwd=~/my-sub-project
```

<strike>It seems to be an option in bower canary but **not currently supported** in stable bower yet according to bower contributor [stazor][1]</strike>

> With bower-canary you have the ability to specify --config.cwd and
>   --config.directory.

When released it will work like this

```
bower install jquery --config.cwd=client
```

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/212

Comment: It is available in current bower versions.

Comment: The location for the documentation for `cwd` changed: https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#cwd

Answer (score 0):

Working directory for bower is in file

```
.bowerrc
```

in the following format

```
{
  "directory": "resources/assets/bower"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Bower uses the current working directory. Just `cd` into the directory you want. No need for an option.

Comment: so what if I'm issuing a remote command and need to define where bower should run at?

Comment: Cd mydir && Bower install

Comment: that doesn't appear to be an option for me.  I'm having problems issues consecutive calls, otherwise I would have already done that.

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir

Comment: That's a problem with the lib you're using, not Bower. Bower does like every CLI tool and uses `$PWD`.

Comment: It appears as if that is the intent of the library. I also highly doubt it uses `$PWD`, more likely some degree of `getcwd` from `libc` which is what most command line tools use. It isn't uncommon for a tool to accept a directory to switch to as a convenience alternative to wrapping commands in `pushd` and `popd` statements